# NSNumberFormatter wrong result

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
NSString *localizedMoneyString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
[numberFormatter release];
```

Result: `€0.89`
Expected result: `0,89€`

No matter `setFormatterBehavior` value the result is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What makes you think this result is wrong?

The position and symbol of the currency indicator doesn't depend only on the currency, it depends on the locale.

I'll give an example, let's have currency code `EUR` (Euro).
Now try to format an amount with a locale set to `en_US` (English, USA) and with `cs_CZ` (Czech, Czech Republic). You'll get `€0.89` and `0,89€` respectively.

Even the symbol can change, let's try it with currency code `CZK` (Czech koruna) - you'll get 
`CZK 0.89` and `0,89 Kc` respectively.

Your result is probably absolutely correct given the locale and currency code.

EDIT:

```
NSLocale* locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_BG"] autorelease];
NSLog(@"%@", [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode]);
NSLog(@"%@", [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator]);
```

Outputs:

```
BGN
.
```

As you can see, the locale is initialized correctly, with region set to Bulgaria (local currency code is BGN) and language set to English (decimal separator is a point). Note that the number formatting is not set from the region. It is set by the language.

So, the problem is not the `NSNumberFormatter` result, the problem is in your expectation, which is wrong.

Comment: With locale - `en_BG@currency=EUR`, expected result is `0.89€`

Comment: But then why currency sign is not after the price?

Comment: Check price labels in app store with this locale - price format must be the same.

Comment: `But then why currency sign is not after the price? ` American locale. what happens for a negative price?

Comment: result is: `(€123.00)` with negative number

Comment: @h4cky, yeah, that is us locale. I was very puzzeled the first time I saw that.